# Apache Nifi Encode XML to ISO-8859-1

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to encode the contents of a XML file from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1, but for the life of me I cannot get it encoded..

I tried using convertCharacterSet but there is no change.

For the Processor I have the following:
Input Character Set: UTF-8
Output Character Set: ISO-8859-1

The input is:

```
<TstH>

    <Header>

        <ProductCode>LOCAL</ProductCode>

        <EffectiveDate>2022-07-18</EffectiveDate>

        <AgencyCode>USER1</AgencyCode>

        <AgencyPassword>pwd1</AgencyPassword>

        <Trace>0</Trace>

    </Header>
</TstH>
```

And my expected output should be:

```
&lt;TstH&gt;

    &lt;Header&gt;

        &lt;ProductCode&gt;LOCAL&lt;/ProductCode&gt;

        &lt;EffectiveDate&gt;2022-07-18&lt;/EffectiveDate&gt;

        &lt;AgencyCode&gt;USER1&lt;/AgencyCode&gt;

        &lt;AgencyPassword&gt;pwd1&lt;/AgencyPassword&gt;

        &lt;Trace&gt;0&lt;/Trace&gt;

    &lt;/Header&gt;
&lt;/TstH&gt;
```

Comment: Easiest is to probably just do a replacetext processor..

Comment: it's not encoding change. you are looking for escaping html/xml. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#escapehtml4 however if you want to change flowfile content then probably better to use replacetext or executescript processors.